# Вывод строки по одному символу JavaScript

Tags: javascript, строки

подскажите, есть строка, хочу вывести ее в хтмл по буквенно, одна за одной с каким-то интервалом, разбиваю строку с помощью split(),  и как теперь ее лучше собрать ?в setTimeout/setInterval через join() или как то циклом перебирать и побуквенно каждый елемент массива вписывать в строку или это все не то?

Comment: а вы пробовали свои же предположения реализовать?

Comment: Пробовал, через join() у меня вообще что-то не выходит, а через цикл получилось с ['h','e','y'] получилось['hh', 'ee', 'yy'], это просто первое что я делаю сам и не очень понимаю что лучше где применять

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let str = 'строка';
const root = document.querySelector('#root');

str.split('').forEach((elem, indx) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    root.textContent += elem;
  }, 500*indx)
});
```

```html
<div id ="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Наверно, перебор для данной задачи, но пусть будет и такой вариант: :)

```js
function show() {
  let txt = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  let pt = new PrintText(txt);
  pt.print();
  let pt2 = new PrintText(txt, 'result2', 1000);
  pt2.print();
}

class PrintText {
  constructor(txt, outId = 'result', interval = 500) {
    let el = document.getElementById(outId);
    if (!el) {
      el = document.createElement('div');
      document.body.appendChild(el);
    }
    this.element = el;
    this.txt = txt;
    this.interval = interval;
    this._curChar = 0;
  }
  print() {
    this.timer = setInterval(this._printNext.bind(this), this.interval);
  }
  _printNext() {
    this.element.textContent += this.txt[this._curChar++];
    if (this.txt.length == this._curChar) clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="txt" type="text" value="Sample text"/>
<input type="button" value="Show text" onclick="show();" />
```